# VueJS 3 Router behaves differently in Dev and Production

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm pretty new to VueJS and have a problem I can't grasp right now.

I coded a little App which works absolutely fine under vue serve, but when I build it and upload the dist folder to my webserver I'm experiencing a weird problem.

I have the following Routes:

```
/home
/overview
/listing
/detail
```

I start at home, click on a button go to overview, from there to listing and from there to detail. Every template has a a "Go Back" Link which works with

```
@click="$router.back()"
```

When testing locally with Vue Serve it behaves as expected.

When I built it and upload the dist folder I get the weird error that when I'm on "Detail" and go back, it goes to "Overview" instead of "listing". I notice that the address in the browser is always one level "off". For example if I go back from overview to home, it shows the home-template but the addressbar shows /listing.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

I already tried $router.go(-1), which results in the same error..

My router file looks pretty standard I'd say:

```
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/overview',
    name: 'Overview',
    component: Overview
  },
  {
    path: '/listing',
    name: 'Listing',
    component: Listing
  },
  {
    path: '/detail',
    name: 'Detail',
    component: Detail
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})

export default router
```

It works great in vue serve mode, but just not when using the dist folder online..

Comment: can you show us your router file? or just try this one instead `$router.go(-1)` where -1 is the number/step to go back.

Comment: @claudios thanks claudios, I tried that but it didn't work either. I've updated my question with my router file. Thank you

Comment: How are you linking to each page? Sounds like it could be replacing the history entry instead of pushing to it

Comment: i go from home -> overview -> listing -> detail, using a function in methods which itself uses "this.$router.push({name:"Listing"})" for example